# Pass javascript variable to server side in php sql query

Tags: php, javascript, sql, html

I have a javascript variable from a previous page that is passed to the header as "namer". Now I also want to use that variable in a sql query in php. How do I go about sending this javascript variable to php on the server side as the variable "namer"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>My Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
                   var namer = sessionStorage.getItem("namer");
                   $('h1').text(namer)
            });
</script>                              
<div data-role="page" class="div1">            
            <div data-role="header"> 
        <h1>"namer"</h1> 
                </div>
        <div data-role="content">  
                <?php
                $link = mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx") OR DIE ("Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.");
                mysql_select_db("abxusername");
                $query = "SELECT class FROM Antibiotics WHERE name="."namer".";";
                echo $query;
                echo mysql_query($query);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-code-in-my-javascript-not-work)

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not sensitive data and you can afford a reload, just use a GET variable.

**client side (javascript)**

```
document.location.href = "?namer=" + namer
```

**Server side (PHP)**

```
if (isset($_GET['namer']) && !empty($_GET['namer'])){
  $namer = $_GET['namer'];
  // Now sanitize data and use it on your SQL query
}
```